# Looking for a data set of geo tracking for a group of users

Tags: data, spatial-analysis

I run a study on user commuting patterns and I need a data set where each line would be something like:

```
userID | Timestamp | lat | long
```

Then, I would like to analyze each user separately and derive insights on his/her commuting patterns. I understand that this kind of data set is rather tricky in terms of privacy, but maybe someone here has an idea?

So far I looked into the following sources:

1. [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/stats/data_stats.html) but here the data points do not contain user IDs (for clear reasons)
2. [Uber](https://github.com/dima42/uber-gps-analysis/tree/master/gpsdata) in this case, the "user" is a taxi driver and his/her commuting patterns are not interesting for my purposes.
3. [GeoLife](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/b16d359d-d164-469e-9fd4-daa38f2b2e13/) looks promising but I fail to download the data set

Any ideas? Sources?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [MIT Reality Mining dataset](http://realitycommons.media.mit.edu/realitymining.html). It's getting a bit old but it contains information on people moving around to the level of cell tower locations rather than data like you would get from a GPS. You'll probably have to do some work to link cell tower IDs to locations too.